# UI that depends on slow loading javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

All of my scripts for a certain page are being concatenating / optimized (requireJS) into a single file. As it stands, my script currently takes a while to load depending upon the browser and the network connection as it is ~ 0.5 MB.

On one of my main landing pages where users are funneled to, I have some interaction (e.g. a button, lets call it "click me button") that is dependent upon that script - event handlers etc. In other words, the button does nothing until the script has been downloaded and loaded: e.g. an empty `href`.

Currently, if testing on an old browser or a slow connection, the user is likely to see all or most of the DOM including "click me button" *before* the script has finished loading. As a result, there is a delay (sometimes up to a few seconds) where clicking on this button does nothing at all.

I am wondering:

1. Is there perhaps a way to architect this such that I can remove the delay between the time the button is shown to when it is clickable (via the JS interaction). Remember all the scripts for this page are concatenated into a single file. I can always try and trim down the size of the file, but this still feels wrong because there is always a theoretically possible lag.
2. Is there anything else in my description that stands out as undesirded architecture. Such as perhaps giving the button a default, non js-dependent, behavior so that if the user does click it immediately something happens - this also feels a bit strange since there would be 2 different behaviors depending on how fast the user happens to click the button.

Comment: 500kB for a single script is pretty big... Can't you use CDNs for common libraries? That way, if it was used by another site visited by the user, it'll be in the user's cache and won't need to be downloaded again. As for the button: Just wrap it with a form that will act as a link, then disable it with your script to do what you want.

Comment: simple solution: default to hiding all of the content until the page is loaded, THEN expose the interactive stuff.

Comment: @MarcB It is simple, but not reliable for users having JS disabled (If OP even cares about them - I don't).

Comment: @blex I agree about the large file size. However even if I wrap the button in a form and disable it via JS (which is sort of what I am doing now), wouldn't there still be a possibility for the user to click the button and submit the form (undesirable) _before_ the script finishes loading?

Comment: Yes, the user would be able to submit it before loading the full script. But that can be solved with a `disabled` attribute on the button (reactivate it later in your JS).

Comment: @blex but doesn't that bring me back to my original post? - the user could potentially be clicking on a button that does nothing for a certain period of time until the script finishes loading.

Comment: Use a small, synchronous script to set the 'pre-load' state and let the large async script set the 'post-load' state.

Comment: Ok, then, if you don't want them to _see_ the button, hide it in CSS as mentioned by Marc.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution might be to use a separate JS function to hide the button in question UNTIL the dependent larger JS file has loaded. Use something like on.load('your JS file) command in conjunction with the hidden css class on that particular button DIV.

```
   onload=function() {

     document.getElementById('BUTTON').className='visible';
}
```

You might also consider separating the JS function in question out and loading it immediately when the DOM is ready. document.ready so that this particular functionality is guaranteed to be available while other UI and JS functionality is still being loaded in the background.

Not sure from your description if either of these is feasible in your particular case but they are something I would consider. Also, have you minified the webpage/CSS/JS code in question to help with loading times? Your file size seems very large, are you including public libraries that you don't need to?

Comment: I have minified the files. But you are correct that I currently have a lot of superfluous libraries that the page in question doesn't need; so this can be refactored. However this still leaves me uneasy because regardless of how small I make the script, there is still that potential for clicking the button with no effect (if the script happens to load slowly for whatever reason). Maybe all I can do it just optimize until it loads quickly _most_ of the time.  Hiding the button until the script loads like some suggested is not feasible from a UX perspective.

Comment: @Jke if you hide it with inline css (e.g.: `<input style="display:none" ...>`), it will be hidden so quickly the user cannot see it. Then, show it back with your JS when it's loaded.

Comment: @blex sorry I may not have explained that properly: I meant that it wasn't feasible from a UX perspective because it wouldn't make sense for a user to see a button suddenly appear on the page (think a big signup button on the top area of a homepage). I do know that it can be achieved technically, but I don't think its good user experience.

Comment: @Jke Oh, ok, I didn't get that. Well, a lot of heavy websites hide the main content in inline CSS, show a loading animation (image or css), and show all of the content when the JS is loaded.

Comment: I think you will be surprised with the performance increase when you remove any extraneous libraries. And if you go a step further and let the public ones be served from a common location you will reduce the load when users have those cached from another site that was using it. Your user may not be able to click the button before the JS loads in most of the cases. I get you about UX though, as I said, I wasn't sure about your particular case. Just throwing out some options that were on the top of the mind. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have same situation in my app where I show user a button on the landing page to login. But the button is not capable yet because JS has not downloaded yet. I simply show a mask when user clicks on the button saying app is initializing and wait until files get downloaded and inside the file I hide the mask (doesnt matter if it was shown earlier).

For your case I have added one more flag (*global variable*) saying if button is clicked. Setting that flag when user clicks on the button and then using that flag in the file downloaded to check if user has clicked on the button and then do whatever you want to do when the button is clicked.

In your `index.html`

```
    var initializationComplete = false;
    var buttonClicked = false;
    function doStuff() {
        if (!initializationComplete) {
            showMask('Initializing App...'); 
            buttonClicked = true;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('click-me-button').onclick = doStuff;

    function showMask(textToShow) {
        var mask = document.getElementById('mask')
        mask.style['z-index'] = 32767;
        mask.style['display'] = "";
        mask.innerHTML = textToShow;
    }
    function hideMask() {
        var mask = document.getElementById('mask')
        mask.style['z-index'] = 0;
        mask.style['display'] = "none";
        mask.innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Inside your script after its ready to do the stuff.

```
    hideMask();
    initializationComplete = true;
    if(buttonClicked){
         buttonEventHandler();
    }

    function buttonEventHandler(){
       //Do button click stuff here
    }
```